# How to pass python arguments via start-process powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I want to open a process as a different user for which I researched a lot and found that no cmd or python script can help me to achieve my goal, but the Start-Process command of powershell can. The issue currently I am facing is while passing arguments to my python script via Start-Process in powershell. I tried using -ArgumentList but that doesn't helped me as I have to pass arguments as a dict to python.
Below is my script which I was running: 

 `Start-Process python.exe "E:\test_installer\src\client\sql_server\sql_agent_
process.py" {"request_type": "backup", "client_id": 15, "request_id": 39431, "bkpset_id": 18, "ppid": 33796, "fromsource": "True"}`

 Can someone please help me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python but If the json dictionary count as one argument, you could do : 
`Start-Process -FilePath python.exe -ArgumentList "E:\test_installer\src\client\sql_server\sql_agent_process.py", '{"request_type": "backup", "client_id": 15, "request_id": 39431, "bkpset_id": 18, "ppid": 33796, "fromsource": "True"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass the argument to the script as a `string` then use the [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it back to dictionary.

In your python script use the `sys.argv` to get the command line argument.

It should look something like this:

```
import sys
import ast
command_line_args = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
```

While the `powershell` command is:

```
Start-Process python.exe "E:\test_installer\src\client\sql_server\sql_agent_
process.py" "{\"request_type\": \"backup\", \"client_id\": 15, \"request_id\": 39431, \"bkpset_id\": 18, \"ppid\": 33796, \"fromsource\": True}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Amiram, it worked fine. I added sys.argv to python and used your ps command to access. Thank you so much.