# Convert string representation of list of dictionaries to list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

This is string representation

```
Data = "[{'Date': '16-Sep-2019', 'Open': 10994.85, 'High': 11052.7, 'Low': 10968.2, 'Close': 11003.5, 'Shares Traded': 434449776, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 15786.17}, {'Date': '17-Sep-2019', 'Open': 11000.1, 'High': 11000.1, 'Low': 10796.5, 'Close': 10817.6, 'Shares Traded': 482013044, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 17721.93}]"
```

i want it to be list representation

```
Data = [{'Date': '16-Sep-2019', 'Open': 10994.85, 'High': 11052.7, 'Low': 10968.2, 'Close': 11003.5, 'Shares Traded': 434449776, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 15786.17}, {'Date': '17-Sep-2019', 'Open': 11000.1, 'High': 11000.1, 'Low': 10796.5, 'Close': 10817.6, 'Shares Traded': 482013044, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 17721.93}]
```

i tried every thing including json.loads(data),
Even after json.loads() it shows type as string.Please check in online compiler also.
Thankyou

Comment: Well eval(string) would technically do it though I'd avoid it for anything but a single use code of my own (or a very trusted source). If that's no good you'd have to know what format of string you were receiving and parse it.

Comment: @tgrtim please help.No its not working with eval.

Comment: You can use the `ast` package. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607551/how-to-pass-python-arguments-via-start-process-powershell/59607626#59607626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use eval function.

```
data=eval("[{'Date': '16-Sep-2019', 'Open': 10994.85, 'High': 11052.7, 'Low': 10968.2, 'Close': 11003.5, 'Shares Traded': 434449776, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 15786.17}, {'Date': '17-Sep-2019', 'Open': 11000.1, 'High': 11000.1, 'Low': 10796.5, 'Close': 10817.6, 'Shares Traded': 482013044, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 17721.93}]")
print(type(data))
print(data[0])
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
{'Date': '16-Sep-2019', 'Open': 10994.85, 'High': 11052.7, 'Low': 10968.2, 'Close': 11003.5, 'Shares Traded': 434449776, 'Turnover (Rs. Cr)': 15786.17}
```

Comment: Simply don't... It would at least be better to use `literal_eval` from `ast`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
L = Data.strip('][').split(', ') 

print(L)
print(type(L))
```

```
res = '['+Data.strip('][')+']'

print(res)
print(type(res))
```

Comment: no its like ["{'Date': '16-Sep-2019'",... i want it to be like [{'Date': '16-Sep-2019',